How to jointly estimate range and delay of a target?
For a radar, it receives echo signal from a target, given as
$$y=\alpha \textbf{b}(\theta)\textbf{a}^T(\theta)s(t-\tau)+n,$$
where $\alpha$ is the amplitude related to the target's RCS and so on, $\textbf{a}(\theta)$ and $\textbf{b}(\theta)$ are the transmit and receive steering vector of the radar, respectively. $\tau$ is the transmit delay.
I want to estimate the delay and angle of the target.
But when the received signal is passed through the matched filter, it becomes
$$r=\alpha \textbf{b}(\theta)\textbf{a}^T(\theta)+n',$$
where the delay information $\tau$ is gone. So my question is how can I jointly derive the CRB of the angle and delay estimatee of the target?
Is it that delay is estimated first and then perform angle estimation?

Read this 3 part write-up on FMCW Radar from Qasim /wireelesspi who contributes to here as well. It's very good and I believe will answer your questions specific to that type of CW radar operation: https://wirelesspi.com/fmcw-radar-part-1-ranging/

How did you derive what the output of the matched filter is supposed to look like? You just simply eliminated the signal $s(t)$ from the output. The matched filter output is a function of time (delay).

Sorry for my expression, the out put of the matched filter should actually be: $r=\int_{T}\alpha\textbf{b}(\theta)\textbf{a}^T(\theta)s(t-\tau)s^*(t-\tau_0)dt+n'$, and then when the time $\tau_0$ matches with the delay $\tau$, the output should be $r=T\alpha\textbf{b}(\theta)\textbf{a}^T+n'$, where T is the processing gain which is the number of symbols transmitted in T?

To simplify things, let's first forget about the transmit side and focus on receive, so we can see the action of receiving and beamforming a signal from a certain angle of arrival for pulse compression (matched-filtering). It should be more clear on how the math works if we go step by step instead of trying to one-shot a result.
The main concern of beamforming is to align (i.e., point the beam) the incoming signals to achieve the maximum SNR before pulse compressing. If your signals across the elements are not aligned, the output of the matched filter will suffer an SNR loss and degrade the shape of our output, such as sidelobes.
In this example, lets use a linear-frequency modulated pulse (LFM) with a pulse width of $10\ \mu s$ and sweeps a bandwidth of $1\ MHz$:

We'll model everything at baseband, assuming that all of the down-conversion/mixing has already been done. The array in use is a $N=16$ element uniform linear array (ULA). Also, we're assuming the narrowband assumption meaning that phase shifts are enough to align the signals, despite there being real delays between the arrival time between elements, but they are so small that we won't consider them. This is usually what is taught when introduced to beam steering.
We'll model a signal that is 1 km away incoming from an angle of 10 degrees at a relatively healthy SNR so we can see what's going on with noise introduced. It will arrive with a delay $\tau$ due to the range. From this angle, the individual signals $s(t-\tau)$ at each element will experience a phase-shift according to the array steering vector $a(\theta)$:
$$a(\theta) = [1 \ e^{jkdsin(\theta)} \ \cdots e^{jkdsin(\theta)(N-1)}]^T$$
Now you have 16 versions of $s(t-\tau)$ each with the corresponding phase shift from $a(\theta)$. Adding some noise and sampling, your collected signals looks like this:

Applying the conjugate of the steering vector, $a(\theta)^*$, phase-shifts the signals to align them. Note the difference between what the unsteered and steered signals look like:

Then when you sum them, you perform the last part of the beamforming step to get the signal that will ultimately be matched-filtered (note that you can format the steering vector and signal matrix to perform the phase shifting and sum in one step):

So here you have a delayed version of the signal $s(t)$ as expected, reconstructed as best we could against noise, among other factors. Now lets see what the output of the matched filter looks like with both the unsteered and steered versions:

You can see that the steered version has a cleaner output, and a higher peak at the correct range of 1 km.
Actual angle estimation is a different beast. There are multiple methods to do this, and it depends on what kind of antenna/array you're using and what kind of accuracy you're trying to get. I think it warrants to be a separate question, but you may find something useful already on the site.

Using matched filtering, the unwanted signals, like the radar sensing signals from other BSs can be eliminated (because the signals transmitted by different BSs can be assumed to be orthogonal?). When I receive a echo signal, is the procedure to estimate the angle and range of the target: matched-filtering, range estimation-->angle estimation using the output of the matched filter?

@Moonie Yeah that's the usual the order of operations. If you're also doing Doppler processing, you could use the Doppler results before matched filtering to determine angle but that is less common.

Thanks for your reply! So if I want to derive the CRB for the range estimation and angle estimation, I can only derive them one by one? I mean, to derive the range estimation CRB using the received signal before matched filtering, and then derive the angle CRB using the output from the matched filter? Is there a way to derive them jointly? And the output of the matched filter seems to be deprived of the delay (range) information that used to lie in $s(t−\tau)$... I am quite confused.@Envidia

I'm not sure what you mean by "one by one". Once you have the data you can perform range and angle estimates on it. I see you asked another question so I'll see if I can answer there.
